# Windows Azure Backup - Fails on Drive C: (OS Drive)

Tags: azure

I am using the following:

- Windows Server 2008
- Windows Azure Backup (latest version from azure site)

I have two drives I am backing up:

- C: (OS Drive)
- G: (Attached Drive 1)

The backups complete fine for Drive G but repeatedly fail for the primary operating system drive C: with the following error message:

An unexpected error occured during the operation. Retry the operation. (0x07EF9).

I have tried the following:

- Re-install Azure Backup & Re-register server
- Create a new Vault and try then
- Defragment hard drive.

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the log from C:\program files\Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent\Temp to get more details, G is fine but C not, should be access permission problem

Comment: I checked that folder on the file: CBUI0Curr.errlog. I scrolled down to the date of the failure and it did not include any error messages or any indication that something failed.

Answer (score 0):

removing all selections for C:\ drive from the job and saving it and then adding them back in again fixed it for me.